# Bash script to manipulate a csv file

Tags: bash, scripting

I have the following csv file:

```
    "V1","V2","V3","V4","V5","V6","V7","V8","V9","V10","Class"
65,Female,0.7,0.1,187,16,18,6.8,3.3,0.9,1
62,Male,10.9,5.5,699,64,100,7.5,3.2,0.74,1
62,Male,7.3,4.1,490,60,68,7,3.3,0.89,1
58,Male,1,0.4,182,14,20,6.8,3.4,1,1
72,Male,3.9,2,195,27,59,7.3,2.4,0.4,1
46,Male,1.8,0.7,208,19,14,7.6,4.4,1.3,1
```

I am only interested in the columns V1:age, V2:sex, V8:grade1, V9:grade2.

I would like to create a bash script that will output the the data where V9 is equal to 3 and sort the output by sex, showing the Female data first.

I am a 100% beginner with bash scripts and although I know how to obtain this output from shell, I could only come up with this when it comes to bash script commands:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

INPUT=./phpOJxGL9.csv
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=','
[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }

echo Grade2 = 3
echo Age Sex Grade2 Grade1 
echo '************************'


while read V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10

do
      if [ $V9 -eg "3" ];
      then
      cut -d',' -f1,2,8,9 | sort -k2 -t','
      fi
      

done < $INPUT
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

The out put should look somewhat like this:

[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: A shell script is pretty much just a sequence of commands. So if you can solve your problem at the command line you can solve it in a shell script by using those same commands. Does this help?

Comment: You might be better with a text processing language like `perl`, `awk`, or `Python` - this task is very easy in Python using the pandas lib and this can be used in a script

Comment: Refine your problem description. Your problem description "V9 is equal to 3" doesn't match any of your example data. This is difficult in `bash`, but easy in languages designed for text handling, like `perl`, Python,...But see `man cut paste bash`.

Comment: I do know that python is a better language to manipulate a csv, but I would like to learn bash scripting. I have managed to get the result with adding shell commands to this script. Thank you @roaima (: the only part I am missing, is filtering the output based on the column value. The if statement does not work, is it a correct way to try to output only the rows for witch the V9 column value is 3?

Comment: The script you post is incomplete -- it just ends in mid-air. The line `if  [$V9 -eg 3]; then` is junk: the variable should be double-quoted, it needs spaces either side of each square bracket, the operator for equal is -eq, none of your data is equal to this, and shell does not do real numbers anyway. This cannot be the script you are running. Pass all scripts through shellcheck.net before running.

Comment: I have updated my script @Paul_Pedant (:

Comment: Btw. The data is just a sample, I could not have uploaded the complete file, but there are rows in which the value of V9 equals 3

Comment: It would be most helpful if your example output matched the example input. Even if you have to calculate it by hand

Comment: If you are only interested in values of 3.0 and above, you can ignore the fractional part, but may need to deal with e.g. 12.4 so you cannot just use the first digit. Bash can use a case value or a string compare in the integer part, and skip lines with a pattern like `[012].*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is already almost finished. The only thing left is to check in an if condition if `V9` is equal to `3`. In order to show female data first, I'd suggest putting the while loop in a function which requires the gender as a first argument and then run the function once for each gender.

```
INPUT=phpOJxGL9.csv
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=','

[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }

function readCsv {
    while read V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
    do
        requiredGender="$1"

        if [[ "$V2" == "$requiredGender" ]]
        then
            if [[ "$V9" == "3" ]]
            then
                echo "$V1,$V2,$V8,$V9"
            fi
        fi
    done < $INPUT
}

echo Grade2 = 3
echo Age Sex Grade2 Grade1 
echo '************************'

echo
echo "Women"
echo "--------------"

readCsv "Female"

echo
echo "Men"
echo "--------------"

readCsv "Male"

IFS=$OLDIFS
```

You'll have to make the script executable in order to run it:

```
chmod +x script.sh
./script.sh
```

Keep in mind that the csv file you provided above doesn't contain a single column where `V9` is equal to `3`, thus running the script above wouldn't output any data. I added those two sample columns:

```
50,Female,,,,,,1,3,,
50,Male,,,,,,1,3,,
```

and this is the script's output:

```
Grade2 = 3
Age Sex Grade2 Grade1
************************

Women
--------------
50,Female,1,3

Men
--------------
50,Male,1,3
```

Answer (score 2):

Your own bash script is a good start. But using suitable tools can make life easier. Here is an example:
Your sample input doesn't have any v9=3, so I have used v9>=3 just to demonstrate the command.

```
tail -n+2 your-input | awk -F, '($9>=3){print $1, $2, $8, $9}' | sort -k2 | awk 'OFS="," {print $1,$2,$3,$4}'

65,Female,6.8,3.3
58,Male,6.8,3.4
62,Male,7,3.3
62,Male,7.5,3.2
46,Male,7.6,4.4
```

Explanation:
tail -n+2 simply removes the title line.

note that we must have tab or space separation before using sort column option

the second awk is to replace spaces by commas